# How to change Controllers/Models source directory in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, models, controllers

I need to load controllers and models from a different folder than the default one. I am using a Linux system.

I am building a simple CI application for some people, for use on a shared hosting I own. But I want to give them access only to /views folder and some /config files. And this is why I need to store the controllers and models in a different folder on the same level as /public_html folder or maybe somewhere in the linux system.

I consider this would be a better solution than encoding files

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter permits you to organize your controllers,views and config files into sub-folders. As far as I know it doesn't permit it for models (at least documentation doesn't mention it, I've not tried myself).

As your are in a Linux system, you can create a **symbolic link** to reference to another directory in the filesystem.

So you can create the directories:

```
application/config/public
application/controllers/public
application/views/public
```

And then create in your /public_html symbolic links ponting to these directories:

```
/public_html/config -> application/config/public
/public_html/controllers -> application/controllers/public
/public_html/views ->application/views/public
```

When your customers upload files to /public_html/config, they will be also available in application/config/public. The same applies for /public_html/controllers and /public_html/views.

The command syntaxis to creates symlinks is

```
# ln -s target name
```

i.e:

```
# ln -s application/config/public /public_html/config
```

If you don't have console access to your hosting you can create the links using the PHP function [symlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) .

To load a view/config/controller from a subfolder you only have tu prepend  the directory name in the $this->load->...() function call. i.e:

```
$this->load->view('public/my_view);
```

Check CI documentation for more info about organizing your files into sub-folders.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking to symbolic links, I know about ln, but could be a bit risky. anyway, have a look here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/158193/

and yes, my method works for libs and models. just checked. tomorrow I'll check yours. thanks.